# Debug builds compile much more slowly than release

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build

Under Visual Studio 2005 we have a single library w/ 195 cpp files which takes about 2 minutes to build for release but about 6 minutes to build for debug.

I always thought release builds should take longer because of optimization. Why would a debug build take so much longer than release? Is there anyway to speed our debug build up to be as fast as release?

We do have a fair amount of boost/stl code.

Comment: Are you using precompiled headers in both?

Comment: Yes PCH on both.  The build options besides /I /D PCH are: /Od /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd  /W4 /nologo /c /Wp64 /ZI /TP /errorReport:prompt    /wd4018 /Zm200.  Yeah I was wondering if we had "write some big optional file" in there.  Times are just to build the library so no linking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to put starbolin's comment down here as **the answer: apples and oranges**. charley's guess of I/O limited did not seem to pan out with my Process Monitor calculation of 600MB written for debug and 300MB for release. That is, writing an extra 300MB would take a few seconds, not  4 minutes. Therefore I conclude there are likely just a bunch things different between Debug and Release builds. Although optimization should take longer than no optimization, these other debug-only activities must take more time than that. Would be nice to see a breakdown of exactly where the time goes for Debug and Release, but it seems clear they are quite different processes and Debug just takes a lot longer, at least for Visual Studio 2005 and the project I benchmarked.

Answer (score 9):

Best guess:  Debug-builds are I/O-limited, while Release-builds are processor-limited (in this case).

We've done extensive benchmarking on our build system -- lots of large projects, some small.  The `DEBUG` builds write out lots of `*.pdb` information, much larger `*.obj` files (for the extra debugging information), etc.  The result is massively-more disk activity.  This is accentuated even further if you have lots of "literals" in your source code (tables, symbols, string-literals), etc.

In contrast, the `RELEASE` builds write out *much* smaller `*.obj` files, and doesn't bother writing the "debug" databases (if you compile `RELEASE` with typical switches).  However, the linker in `RELEASE` builds has to do its optimizations and other significantly-more work that is just not done in `DEBUG`, so it's processor-bound.  This is further time-penalized for `RELEASE` if you "compile-to-maximize-speed/size" with the most challenging-to-the-linker switches.

(However, yes, the `RELEASE` build must still I/O update-the-addresses in the executable-being-built-on-disk, but since the executable is so much smaller in the `RELEASE` build, you page much less, so the I/O penalty in `RELEASE` build is not as much as for `DEBUG` build.)

You're observing a 3x "`RELEASE` is more expensive than `DEBUG`".  That's about right for some projects that are I/O-bound with lots of templates, many symbols and literals, etc.  Check your drives -- are they getting full, or just "slow-drives", and/or with some bad sectors?  Those will make it worse (slower) for the `DEBUG` builds.

Yes, other builds should be the other-way-around, with "`RELEASE` something like 3x more-expensive than `DEBUG`".  Those builds are processor/linker-bound, rather than I/O-bound.

**[UPDATE]**, I see in the comment-on-the-question that this is for "static-library, no-linking".  That's pretty-much the worst-case-scenario for a time-penalty for I/O (lots of disk activity, no linking), and without a processor-penalty (since no optimizations are being done).  So, if you have a 3x "`DEBUG`-is-slower-than-`RELEASE`", that's probably about as bad as it can get (for this project), and that's not atypical.  When you add linking options, the `RELEASE` will get slower.

Comment: Writing files is really cheap in Windows thanks to the file system cache's lazy write-back.  This answer only makes sense if the machine is severely RAM constrained.  Could happen, but generating a gigabyte worth of object/debug data is not that easy.

Comment: @Hans, sort-of-agree. Lazy-writes help, but we've found the NTFS to be amazingly expensive for almost all file operations as compared with other file systems. If files are cached/transferred through network resources, of course, lazy writes won't help at all (e.g., build farms, distributed build systems).  Win7 added further file-handle penalty/latency weirdness over XP/Vista (due to Win7 security improvements), and caused us all kinds of file/port-handle problems with our embedded systems.

Comment: [This blog post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2011/05/10/how-to-check-how-many-writes-are-done-while-you-build.aspx) describes how to measure bytes written in debug and release.  Note you have to monitor devenv.exe and cl.exe.  It came out to about 300MB written for release and 600MB written for debug.  I tested just in the shell copying 1GB of stuff and that takes about 10 seconds.  Therefore it doesn't _seem_ to me that writing at extra 300MB could really take 4 minutes longer. There must be other compiler activity which is taking a long time besides just IO.